# Is it possible for iOS application to directly play youtube video in cardboard mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, google-cardboard

I've been searching a lot but still didn't find an answer.

Im using youtube-ios-player-helper https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper to view youtube videos in my app.

Is it possible to play video automatically in cardboard mode? and if yes, how can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use embed link

```
NSString *videoURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/..(Your youtube video link)";
```